# PHP: GET-data automatically being declared as variables

Tags: php, url, get

Take this code:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['action']) && !empty($_POST['action'])) {
    $action = $_POST['action'];
}

if ($action) {
    echo $action;
}
else { 
    echo 'No variable';
}
?>
```

And then access the file with ?action=test
Is there any way of preventing $action from automatically being declared by the GET? Other than of course adding

```
&& !isset($_GET['action'])
```

Why would I want the variable to be declared for me?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Check your php.ini for the `register_globals` setting. It is probably on, you want it off.

> Why would I want the variable to be declared for me?

[You don't.](https://www.php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php) It's a horrible security risk. It makes the Environment, GET, POST, Cookie and Server variables global [(PHP manual)](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.register-globals). These are a handful of [reserved variables](http://us.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.php) in PHP.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it's really what I've been looking for. But is my example the only thing register_globals affects?

Comment: I posted a bit more in the answer above -- it affects environment, get, post, cookie and server.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like `register_globals` in your php.ini is the culprit. You should turn this off. It's also a huge security risk to have it on.

If you're on shared hosting and can't modify php.ini, you can use [ini_set()](http://php.net/ini_set) to turn register_globals off.

Answer (score 2):

Set register_globals to off, if I'm understanding your question.
See https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.predefined.php

Answer (score 2):

if you don't have access to the *php.ini*, a `ini_set('register_globals', false)` in the php script won't work (variables are already declared) 
An *.htacces*s with:

```
php_flag register_globals Off
```

can sometimes help.

Answer (score 1):

You can test, whether all variables are declared properly by turning the PHP log-level in PHP.INI to

```
error_reporting  =  E_ALL
```

Your code snippet now should generate a NOTICE.

Answer (score 1):

At some point in php's history they made the controversial decision to turn off register_globals by default as it was a huge security hazard. It gives anyone the potential to inject variables in your code, create unthinkable consequences! This "feature" is even removed in php6

If you notice that it's on contact your administrator to turn it off.